# How to align many images of different sizes

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my CSS. I have an array that takes 50 images from the database. Images are of different sizes. I wanted to align these images in such a way that rows of Images are created. Rows could be of any height(some reasonable). There could be different number images in each row. Basically I'm inspired from many photo gallery and stock websites like fotolia and shutterstock. When I search they give me 100 images each of them are also of different sizes but they align them in a way that width remains same. I know these companies are very big. But I wanted to understand is it just possible to do it with css or it also requires with php(for computing how images should be stacked.

[image: Fotolia Image showing how they stack photos]

Images could have different dimensions but they align in such a way that they take the total width of the div.

I tried many times with setting max-width and width values but they do not give me the desired result.
Anyone please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably not with CSS unless one dimension of the image is always the same...even then some scaling/distortion is likely.

Comment: latest time I took money for that

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is awesome for this, I had tried a bunch of Javascript libraries and none of them wanted to play nicely with Gulp and Bower so I tried to find another route and Flexbox was a very easy (and better IMO) alternative. Kudos to you for attempting to use CSS rather than over complicate with JS.

This has been the best tutorial I've found on the internet for this and it helped me when I was in your shoes.

This should get you headed in the correct direction & you might want to also consider setting a max-height to your inner-images.

Happy Coding, and let me know if you have questions!

https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.eule88uh2

and further - a helper on flex to understand about parent containers and inner elements:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

something like this might get you started

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <img class="inner-image portrait" />
    <img class="inner-image landscape" />
    <img class="inner-image portrait" />
    <img class="inner-image landscape" />
    <img class="inner-image portrait" />
    <img class="inner-image landscape" />
    <img class="inner-image portrait" />
    <img class="inner-image landscape" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start; /* should align items to the top of your flex row if they don't reach 100px in height */
}
.inner-image {
    max-height: 100px;
}
.inner-image.portrait {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
.inner-image.landscape {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This is untested, but conceptually should be correct and can be understood and expanded upon with the links I included.

Comment: With flexbox images are not scaled they are just placed like cards and image with larger height created a lot of vacant space. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works fine but it does not respect the aspect ratio of the images. It just places the image by scaling the images without keeping the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Is there is anyone who could help me doing this. I believe php or javascript is required. If anyone could give me some clue about how to solve this problem.